# How to fail maven build only at end?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a maven build which has two modules. 
Both modules contain failing tests. Module B has a dependency on Module A.

I would like to run my build and let it only fail at the end.

The test error in module A will unfortunately mark module A as unstable and cause building of module B to be skipped:

```
[INFO] Skipping testmaven B
[INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
```

Is there a way to continue with the tests but let the maven build fail at the end? I tried the `-fae` option but that does not change the behaviour.

I would like to avoid using `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` if possible.

Comment: If you have failing tests which means from my point of view that you need to fix your tests or your code. On the other hand and don't want to use `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` which does not make sense? Maybe I misunderstand a thing here?

Comment: I thought it would be good to let the maven process fail with a non zero exit code but I guess your point is valid. I only thought there would be perhaps another option which I did not know. I guess using the flag is okay since I already run the test phase in a dedicated jenkins step. That step examines the junit results files.